# Change `<input>` element attributes from objective-C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, http

I'm trying to change the value of an `element` in a `<input type="checkbox">` from `null` to `checked`.
How would I do this from objective-C (iOS application)?

Here's the relevant `HTML` of the page

```
<td align="right" width="15%" class="darkNeutral">
    <input id="chk_Assignments" type="checkbox" class="ShowAll" />
    <label for="chk_Assignments">Show All</label>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
```

I was thinking I'd use `POST` or something, but I'm not sure how to access the element, add a `checked` attribute, and set the value of the attribute to `"checked"`.

Comment: basically, I want to 'check' the checkbox

Comment: `UIWebView` has a method called `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` that may allow you to accomplish your goal, assuming that you're viewing that HTML in a UIWebView.

Comment: Please clarify your question - What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you attempting to POST data to a web page with the checkbox ticked?  Are you trying to manipulate the HTML that is rendered in a UIWebView?

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm trying to check the tickbox, so make the line `<input id="chk_Assignments" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="ShowAll" />`

Comment: But where is the HTML?  in a UIWebView?  Are you trying to trigger the javascript associated with the checkbox?

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm trying to also figure out how to get the `HTML`, because after I change the `<input checkbox>`, the site uses `AJAX` to fetch the userData that's inserted into the `HTML` of the page. So I'm thinking I'm going to have to use a `UIWebView`, but I'm not 100% sure how to implement that after logging in using `NSURLConnection`. This is where I'm trying to figure out how to get the `HTML` data -> 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588427/ios-objective-c-wait-for-ajax-before-downloading-html-from-webpage

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *javaScript = @"document.getElementById('chk_Assignments').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');";

// Make the UIWebView method call
NSString *response = [webViewA stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
NSLog(@"javascript result: %@", response);
```

If HTML page got jQuery included, the javascript could be simplified:

```
NSString *javaScript = @"$('#chk_Assignments').attr('checked', 'checked');";
NSString *response = [webViewA stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
NSLog(@"javascript result: %@", response);
```

Comment: I first need to get a `UIWebView` in my project, so I'll try this as soon as I get there. Thank you.

Also, this is where I'm trying to figure out where I'll access the data -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588427/ios-objective-c-wait-for-ajax-before-downloading-html-from-webpage