# How to Change `<input>` element attributes(e.g. value) from objective-C in wkWebview/webView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webview, wkwebview

Ok, I Found Certain [links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22587021/4125508) from this site,

but the issue is what if the tag doesn't consist id or name?

```
<input type="email" class="_style_3vhmZK" placeholder="Email: name@example.com" value="" data-reactid="49">
```

I tried like this:

**TRY Number 1:**

```
 NSString *javaScript1 = @"var passFields = document.document.getElementsByTagName('input'); \
            passFields[0].setAttribute('value','Naman')";   [webView evaluateJavaScript:javaScript1 completionHandler:nil];
```

**TRY Number 2**

```
 NSString *javaScript = @"document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute('value','Naman Vaishnav');";    [webView evaluateJavaScript:javaScript1 completionHandler:nil];
```

But still not achieve Target, Enlighten me if I'm making any mistakes...

Comment: I don't have an experience with Obj-c but suggesting use ClassName instead of TagName

Comment: Could you please show me how to change the value via className ? because i 've tried it and could not able to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done Via Tags , Welcome to more sufficient way if there is any ,

```
  NSString *javaScript1 = @"var passFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); \
           for (var i = passFields.length>>> 0; i--;) { if(passFields[i].placeholder == 'Email: name@example.com'){ passFields[i].value ='%@';}}";

            NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javaScript1,emailInfo[0]];
            [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascriptWithCSSString completionHandler:nil];
```